# Can't locate RRDs.pm in @INC

Tags: rrdtool

If i run any of my perl script without "use lib qw( /opt/rrdtool-1.4.4/lib/perl );" after perl interpreter. I've to face the following error.

Can't locate RRDs.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .)

Its hard for me to use: "use lib qw( /opt/rrdtool-1.4.4/lib/perl );" in all of my scripts because there are hundreds of scripts. Can anyone help to resolve this....?

Answer (score 7):

In ubuntu systems :

> sudo apt-get install librrds-perl

Comment: in debian the package is: librrdtool-oo-perl

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple options: symlink the rrdtool stuff somewhere into @INC, probably `/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl` or set/add to the variable `PERL5LIB` to `/opt/rrdtool-1.4.4/lib/perl`. Scripts run with taint checks ignore `PERL5LIB`.

Comment: I've use varible PERL5LIB. I can run scrip manulay. but it does not work with cron...

Answer (score 0):

`export PERL5LIB=${PERL5LIB}:/opt/rrdtool-1.4.4/lib/perl`

Comment: Thanks,... I've done after post by embobo.
export PERL5LIB=/opt/rrdtool-1.4.4/lib/perl and i've get red of the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this issue when I tried to install collected-web. Finally solved by running `cpan -i JSON`.