# Where to get RRDs.pm?

Tags: centos, perl, rrdtool, opsview

I'm trying to set up opsview (Nagios) on a CentOS 5 server running perl 5.8.9

When I try to start it, it can't find `RRDs.pm`.  Turns out, neither can I.  It's not on CPAN and I've been unable to determine what package would provide it.  `yum provides "*/RRDs.pm"` doesn't return any results.

Edit: so we've established that it *should* come with the `perl-rrdtool` package, but unfortunately hasn't. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/181103/cant-locate-rrds-pm-in-inc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RRDs.pm should be provided by [perl-rrdtool](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=perl-rrdtool), but you indicate that you've already installed this program.

Your script can't find RRDs.pm, but RRDs.pm may still be installed on your system, just not in a place where PERL expects to find it.

What do one of these commands tell you?

(You might need to update the `locate` database first, with `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate` or a similar cron command)

```
locate RRDs.pm
```

Or:

```
find / -type f -name RRDs.pm
```

Comment: I did find an old RRDs.pm in under the perl 5.8.8 libs, but after copying it into the 5.8.9 tree it jsut segfaults.

Comment: I pointed you to the i386 files (I corrected the link). You might have the x86_64 architecture. Make sure you are downloading the correct RPM for your architecture: http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=perl-rrdtool

Comment: CentOS 5.5 ships with Perl 5.8.8 by default. If you are using Perl 5.8.9, then it sounds like you are starting to go the custom route. A simpler solution would be to stick with the default version of Perl, unless you really need a newer version of Perl.

Comment: This time you've hit it.  Running `strings` against the rpm it appears to be hardcoded to install under perl 5.8.8.  I've reverted to 5.8.8 and it's now working!  Hopefully there wasn't a good reason I'd upgraded to 5.8.9

Answer (score 2):

Running the following fixed this issue for me on RHEL6.

```
yum install rrdtool-perl
```

Comment: This answer will be better if you also explain what the differences between those two packages are.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install rrdtool, CentOS doesn't provide this package by default but you can use [Dag Wiers' repository](http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/FAQ.php)

```
$ cd /etc/yum.repos.d
$ vim dag.repo
```

insert the following lines:

```
[dag]
name=Dag RPM Repository
baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el$releasever/en/$basearch/dag
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
enabled=1
```

and :wq (save) the file. After this, just install the package via yum.

```
$ yum install rrdtool
```

Comment: Unfortunately I already had `rrdtool-1.4.4-1.el5.rf.i386` installed from the CentOS repository, so that's not it either

Answer (score -1):

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager
This system is registered to Red Hat Subscription Management, but is not receiving updates. You can use subscription-manager to assign subscriptions.
http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el7Server/en/x86_64/dag/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: apt.sw.be; Name or service not known"
Trying other mirror.
```

One of the configured repositories failed (Dag RPM Repository),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.
2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
       upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
       distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
       packages for the previous distribution release still work).
3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

   ```
       yum-config-manager --disable dag
   ```
4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
       Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
       so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
       slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
       compromise:

   ```
       yum-config-manager --save --setopt=dag.skip_if_unavailable=true
   ```

> failure: repodata/repomd.xml from dag: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
>       http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el7Server/en/x86_64/dag/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: apt.sw.be; Name or service not known"

Comment: This in now way attempts to answer the posted question.